# Does duplicating a script tag cause problems? Is it better to use $.getScript('example.js')

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using the following syntax the Google Tag Manager script gets loaded first (asynchrounously) and the following code can already access the variables like `gtag`.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-1234567');
</script>
```

In my use case it can happen, that

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567"></script>
```

sometimes gets already added by some other code further above (but not always).

Shall I simply duplicate the script tag?

```
// inserted by some other code
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567"></script>


// now my code starts
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-1234567');
</script>
```

Or, shall I check if the `gtag` variable has been initialized, and if not use `$.getScript('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567')` to load and execute my script.

If the second solution is the better one, can I similarly as above add my code in sequence, or do I have to encapuslate it in `$.getScript('example')`?

This

```
<script>
    $.getScript('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567');
    gtag('do something');
</script>
```

or this

```
<script>
    $.getScript('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567', function(){
        gtag('do something');
    });
</script>
```

If it only works with encapsulation, why does it work fine in sequence when using the script tag and not when using $.getScript('example.js') ?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567"></script>
```

Comment: It probably won't cause a problem. It should just define functions, and redefining the functions with the same definitions should be fine.

Comment: @Barmar: If I choose to use $.getScript(), can I also use the code in sequence?

Comment: No, you should call the functions in the callback, since `$.getScript()` is asynchronous.

Comment: @Barmar: But so is `<script async src="example.js"></script>` (also asynchronous), that's what confuses me.

Comment: I didn't notice that earlier. I'm not sure how the original code is working properly.

Comment: I was only answering the question about whether duplicating is OK. I don't know why you can call a function that's defined in an async script tag.